# Live and Static NodeLists

Tags: javascript, dom, htmlcollection

Ok, so i was playing around with static || live nodelists, trying to test the concept, i have tried different scenarios but there are two scenarios that caught my attention:

```
var toBeLogged = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
console.log(toBeLogged.length); // Returns 1 to the console
var newEl = document.createElement('p');
document.body.appendChild(newEl);
console.log(toBeLogged.length); // Returns 2 to the console
```

which makes sense since the getElementsBy... is a live node collection so it's obviously going to return the updated value when asking for the value again after the update.

but the scenario number two with a small change makes the "Live" nodelist act as a static:

```
var toBeLogged = document.getElementsByTagName('p').length;
console.log(toBeLogged); // Returns 1 to the console
var newEl = document.createElement('p');
document.body.appendChild(newEl);
console.log(toBeLogged); // Returns 1 also to the console
```

so my question is : why the variable created to represent the length property of a live nodelist is not returning a live value as in the value of the variable representing directly the nodelist without adding properties.

i am trying to describe things accurately as much as i can.
Thanks in advance. appreciate your time spent on it.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName('p').length` returns immutable primitive value, it can't be changed, it can be replaced only. `.length` return new primitive values every time you access it, while `document.getElementsByTagName('p')` returns same object every time.

Comment: Thanks, Good sufficient explanation. appreciate it Maxx.